# Internet Connection problems with PPPoE over Fiber

Tags: networking, internet, pppoe

I have a Fiber Optic Internet connection, where the Fiber Optic modem is connected to my Wi-Fi router.

On every system that needs to connect to the Internet, I need to connect to the Wi-Fi router first, and then login via PPPoE with the ISP username and password.

Is there a way to set this up in the router? I have a 3COM 3CRWDR200A-75 router, and I have  tried to set it up to authenticate via PPPoE automatically.

To do this, I have set the Internet Settings, with the ISP username and password. However, this doesn't work. I still have to connect in Windows 7 via PPPoE.

Any help in setting this up would be appreciated, because I'm tearing my hair out!

Answer (score 1):

It seems your Internet router is having some problem with the PPPoE settings. That's why your Internet router is not connecting. Check the setting of your router, such as:

```
VPI : 0
VCI : 50
```

Right now your Wi-Fi router is working as a switch. Try to change some settings and save and restart the router every time you change any settings.